# Search for a specific value inside a Generic list

Tags: c#, generics, delegates

The purpose of the below code is to find a specific value within a generic list using List.Find() method . I am pasting a code below :

```
class Program
{
    public static List<Currency> FindItClass = new List<Currency>();        

    public class Currency
    {
        public string Country { get; set; }
        public string Code { get; set; }
    }        

    public static void PopulateListWithClass(string country, string code)
    {
        Currency currency = new Currency();
        currency.Country = country;
        currency.Code = code;

        FindItClass.Add(currency);
    }

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        PopulateListWithClass("America (United States of America), Dollars", "USD");
        PopulateListWithClass("Germany, Euro", "EUR");
        PopulateListWithClass("Switzerland, Francs", "CHF");
        PopulateListWithClass("India, Rupees", "INR");
        PopulateListWithClass("United Kingdom, Pounds", "GBP");
        PopulateListWithClass("Canada, Dollars", "CAD");
        PopulateListWithClass("Pakistan, Rupees", "PKR");
        PopulateListWithClass("Turkey, New Lira", "TRY");
        PopulateListWithClass("Russia, Rubles", "RUB");
        PopulateListWithClass("United Arab Emirates, Dirhams", "AED");

        Console.Write("Enter an UPPDERCASE 3 character currency code and then enter: ");

        string searchFor = Console.ReadLine();

        Currency result = FindItClass.Find(delegate(Currency cur) { return cur.Code == searchFor; });

        Console.WriteLine();
        if (result != null)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(searchFor + " represents " + result.Country);
        }
        else
        {
            Console.WriteLine("The currency code you entered was not found.");
        }            
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
```

My query is why List is static , what is the purpose of using static over there.

```
 public static List<Currency> FindItClass = new List<Currency>();
```

Another query is why a delegate is used over there inside the find method.

```
Currency result = FindItClass.Find(delegate(Currency cur) { return cur.Code == searchFor; });
```

Comment: *Why `List` is static?* That should be a question pointed to the writer of this program. Regarding the `delegate`, that is because `Find` expects a `Predicate<T>`, where `T` is the type of your list, so you can provide an [*anonymous method*](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0yw3tz5k.aspx) to it.

Comment: Google `static`, i'm sure you'll find an answer. The `delegate` keyword isn't necessary anymore. You can write: `FindItClass.Find(cur => cur.Code == searchFor);`

Comment: What are your thoughts about why a delegate was used for `.Find`? Have you considered what the alternatives are?

Comment: What are you trying to do? Just use `List.Find`?

Comment: I am trying to search a specific value inside generic list . I was also surprised as why delegate is used over here. that is why i asked such a question in first place.

Answer (score 1):

The list is static because it is in a small console app.  Since Main is static, it can only access static variables in the "Program" class without creating a new instance of "Program".

The static keyword indicates that there will be one instance of that variable in the entire program.  In general, developers should default to not use static variables unless they are explicitly sure that they want a single instance of the variable.

As the comments state, the use of the delegate keyword is now optional when calling Find.  The purpose of the delegate argument is to pass a function that will be executed against each item in the list to locate the items that return true.

In modern C#, you could write that line as follows:

```
Currency result = FindItClass.Find(cur => cur.Code == searchFor);
```